# MATLab, plotting a graph with a function

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble writing this code. So, I'm trying to make a code for

func = y*x(n) + z * x(n)

All the values are arbitrary and x(n) is the value at the position n. I need to plot a graph at each nth position. So if x(1) = 5 I plot a point at when x=1 and y=5. The issue is that I can't figure out how to make an arbitrary array and don't know how to get the answer for func when I add x(n) value at the nth position. I also am having trouble plotting a graph, but think this is because I can't figure out to use the array yet.

I'm new to MatLab.

Comment: Could you please check the formula? I can not understand the relationship between y and x.

Comment: y and z are arbitrary values. x(n) is a value x at the nth position of an array. When I plot the graph, I'll be plotting the x axis at the nth position and the value for func at the y axis.

Comment: Here you will find lots of good resources about MATLAB: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab/info -- I strongly suggest you read some introductory tutorials to learn to use the tool, it'll be a lot less painful than trying to learn it by asking questions here.

Comment: how can you plot the func at the y axis if the func itself is a function of y?

Answer (score 0):

So if I am following y & z are just constants?  I think the confusion is typically this would be written something like "y = a*x +b*x"

Like Cris Luengo mentioned in the comments above, you should should go over some basic Matlab tutorials as this is very basic.

```
% y and Z are constants
y = 1;
z = 2;
%this makes x = [0,1,2,...10];
x = 0:1:10;
func = y.*x + z.*x;
plot(func)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
% Define X as a range between -10 to 10 (+1 on every step)...
x = -10:10;

% Define your constants...
y = 3;
z = -1;

% Define the function...
fun = @(x) (y .* x) + (z .* x);

% Plot X on the x-axis and fun(x) on the y-axis...
% fun(x) numerically evaluates fun for the given x
plot(x,fun(x));
```

Refer to [this page](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) for more information about anonymous functions.